# Writing an excel formula as a pandas series does not hold any result

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a `df` which I am writing to an excel.

But first I create a new dataframe which has a column and its value is an excel formula.

```
next_sheet = pd.DataFrame()
next_sheet['SUM'] = '=SUM(first!D2:first!D4)'
```

As you can see, sheets `second & third` share the same formula inside of them.

```
df_res.to_excel('testing.xlsx', sheet_name='first') # main sheet with data

with pd.ExcelWriter('testing.xlsx',  engine="openpyxl", mode="a") as writer: 
    pd.DataFrame(data = ['=SUM(first!D2:first!D4)'], columns = ['SUM']).to_excel(writer, sheet_name='second')
    next_sheet.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='third')
```

But when I write run this code, the first and second sheet is written as expected, the first one just has the raw data, second one has column `SUM` and the `SUM` of values from the `first` sheet, but the `third` sheet has only a column name `SUM` but no values below it.

Second sheet:

[image]

Third sheet:

[image]

My goal is to be able to write a dataframe with formulas instead of raw values which I would then append to an existing excel file as a new sheet. Where is my mistake in approaching it as an example in `third` sheet?
I have followed [this example](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-work-with-excel-files-in-pandas-c584abb67bfb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What happens?

You create an empty dataframe and try to set the column `SUM` to your value, but there are no rows in your dataframe to operate on. So it only creates the new empty column.

#### How to fix?

Assign your data with your new column `SUM` to your empty dataframe:

```
next_sheet = next_sheet.assign(SUM=['=SUM(first!D2:first!D4)'])
```

or as already done directly with creating your dataframe:

```
next_sheet = pd.DataFrame(data = ['=SUM(first!D2:first!D4)'], columns = ['SUM'])
```

#### Example

```
import pandas as pd
next_sheet = pd.DataFrame()
next_sheet = next_sheet.assign(SUM=['=SUM(first!D2:first!D4)'])

with pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx',  engine="openpyxl", mode="a") as writer: 
    pd.DataFrame(data = ['=SUM(first!D2:first!D4)'], columns = ['SUM']).to_excel(writer, sheet_name='second')
    next_sheet.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='third')
```

Comment: That explains it, thank you.